# Can't debug Java Windows Services with jhat, jps, jstack

Tags: java, windows, windows-services

I frequently showcase the jhat, [jps](http://java.sun.com/j2se/1.5.0/docs/tooldocs/share/jps.html), and jstack tool set to developers on Linux and Mac.  However, a developer recently indicated that these are unusable in Windows if the Java app in question is running as a [Windows Service](http://confluence.sakaiproject.org/display/DOC/Tomcat+as+a+Windows+Service+(2.5)).

A [Sun-filed bug says something very similar](https://bugs.java.com/bugdatabase/view_bug?bug_id=6506455), but was closed due to inactivity.

I have tested this out for myself, and indeed it appears true, though I can hardly believe it.  Here is the setup:

1. Tomcat or similar running as a Windows service with the "Log On As" == "Local System"
2. A user with Admin privileges logged in to the same Windows machine.
3. Admin opens Windows Task Manager, can see java.exe running
4. Admin opens console, types "jps", gets back a list of processes that does not include Tomcat's java service process.
5. As a brute force attempt, get the PID of tomcat as a service from Windows Task Manager.  Type jstack < pid >.  Get a reply: < pid > no such process

This appears reproducible under Windows XP, Windows 2003 Server, and Windows 7.  Java versions 1.5 and 1.6 yield the same outcome.

Is there a way from the terminal, even though logged in as Admin, to "sudo up" to get JPS and the other tools to see the java service?

Comment: Have you tried (or is it an option) to connect using the remote management options instead of a PID?

Comment: We may have to resort to that -- setting up a jstatd in the Service executor to expose the java process over a socket -- but the objective was just to do it via PID. I just want to confirm I'm not missing anything here. This seems like a huge hurdle with Windows yet is a non-issue on Mac/BSD/Linux.

Comment: Did Devon_C_Miller's answer resolve this for you? I run jconsole as SYSTEM, but this didn't didn't eliminate the problem (see my comment on the Devon_C_Miller's answer)

Answer (score 8):

To get the utilities to run, you can connect to the Console session using "mstsc /admin" using a login account (not sure exact permissions it needs to have, mine was in the Administrators group) and use the Sysinternals psexec tool to run as system. Here is an example of using jstack.exe:

```
psexec -s "%JAVA_HOME%\bin\jstack.exe" PID >stack.txt
```

Where PID is the process ID of your process. You may also have to substitute the actual path to your JDK depending upon your specific environment.

Also, the [TEMP directory must be set correctly](http://blogs.oracle.com/lmalventosa/entry/jconsole_local_process_list_on) or once again the tools will not work.

Answer (score 4):

I've  had luck debugging processes run by the SYSTEM user by running this from a command prompt:

```
c:> time/t
11:18 AM
c:> at 11:19 /interactive cmd.exe
Added a new job with job ID = 1
```

Use a time 1 minute in the future. When the "at" job runs a windows command prompt will open running as the user SYSTEM. From there you should be able to see the java processes.

If the service is running as a local user (check the details from "mmc %windir%\system32\SERVICES.MSC" by double clicking on the service and selecting the "Log On" tab) you can do the same thing using "runas":

```
runas /user:USERNAME cmd.exe
```

Comment: See this related question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/77528/how-do-you-run-cmd-exe-under-the-local-system-account

Comment: I know see the services in jconsole, but can't connect to them (they are grayed out). When I manually try to connect to the port, I can't. CurrPorts shows the correct port is definitely listened to by the JVM.

Comment: Note: this approach will not work under Vista or Win7 unless you disable the UAC http://www.howtogeek.com/howto/windows-vista/4-ways-to-make-uac-less-annoying-on-windows-vista/

Comment: I haven't tried it yet, but here's an article on writing a service that opens a SYSTEM console: http://www.codeproject.com/KB/vista-security/SubvertingVistaUAC.aspx

Answer (score 1):

You only get those processes that "belong" to you - same user id.

Can you connect to it with jvisualvm?

Comment: Can't get to the processes with jvisualvm either.  Apparently jps and jvisualvm use the identical underlying lib/api for their interrogation (jvmstat)

Answer (score 1):

I've only found a suggest to run visuamvm (or other tools) as windows service: [Monitoring Java Processes Running As a Windows Service](http://blogs.oracle.com/nbprofiler/entry/monitoring_java_processes_running_as)

Perhaps someone else knows a better solution.

Answer (score 1):

This is my batch file to record a thread dump:

```hs
:: Creates a thread dump for the tomcat6.exe process saved in a timestamped filename and views it!
:: Jim Birch 20111128 rev 2015-10-12

::Note this required the following files to be placed in the confluence jre/bin folder:
:: 
:: attach.dll  - From the Java JDK  (must be the same version)
:: tools.jar   - ditto
:: psexec.exe  - from Windows sysinternals
:: Also, the TEMP directory must be set (stack overflow)
set TEMP=c:\windows\temp

::go to run location
d:
cd \confluence.application\jre\bin

::build datetime filename
rem datetime from wmi.exe
for /f "tokens=2 delims==" %%I in ('wmic os get localdatetime /format:list') do set dt0=%%I
rem  datetime string as YYYY-MM-DD-hhmmss
set dt=%dt0:~0,4%-%dt0:~4,2%-%dt0:~6,2%-%dt0:~8,6%
set ff=td-%dt%.txt
echo filename: %ff%

::tomcat PID   
FOR /F "tokens=2" %%I in ('TASKLIST /NH /FI "IMAGENAME eq tomcat6.exe"' ) DO SET PID=%%I
ECHO pid: %PID%

::combine above with jstack command (won't work without psexec)
psexec -s "D:\confluence.application\jre\bin\jstack.exe" -l %PID%  >>  %ff%

:: view output txt file
start %ff%

::pause to review script operation, or use ping to wait a few secs 
::ping localhost -n 20 >nul
pause
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is the solution that finally worked for me for obtaining stacktraces from unprepared java process running under different user in terminal session or as windows service.

**jstack.cmd**:

```hs
@for /f "usebackq tokens=2" %%I in (`tasklist /NH /FI "imagename eq tomcat.exe" /FI "username eq SYSTEM"`) DO set PID=%%I
@for /f "tokens=2 delims==." %%G in ('wmic os get localdatetime /value') do @set datetime=%%G
@set date_time=%datetime:~0,4%_%datetime:~4,2%_%datetime:~6,2%__%datetime:~8,2%_%datetime:~10,2%_%datetime:~12,2%
PsExec.exe /accepteula -h -s -d cmd /c "%JAVA_HOME%\jstack.exe" -l %PID% ^>"%~dp0jstack_%date_time%.txt"
```

First line [determines](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8435952/how-to-get-pid-from-command-line-filtered-by-username-and-imagename) the PID by process name and user.

Then [PsExec](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/downloads/psexec) with [accepted EULA](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14140826/using-psexec-in-a-windows-service) helps to call [jstack](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/guides/troubleshoot/tooldescr016.html) in [elevated mode](https://superuser.com/questions/540380/psexec-access-is-denied) with [properly escaped](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17113343/redirect-output-of-command-in-for-loop-of-batch-script) redirection of the [output](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/796476/displaying-windows-command-prompt-output-and-redirecting-it-to-a-file) to `jstack*.txt` file in script's dir with [timestamp included in file name](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1192476/format-date-and-time-in-a-windows-batch-script/23558738#23558738).

You may need to add PsExec and JDK dirs to [PATH](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2079635/how-can-i-set-the-path-variable-for-javac-so-i-can-manually-compile-my-java-wor) beforehand.

I've tried to force threaddumps by [SendSignal](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/813086/can-i-send-a-ctrl-c-sigint-to-an-application-on-windows) before but it never worked reliably with Windows service processes.

Comment: The datetime value can be obtained without WMIC, as follows:

set DATETIME=%date:~10,4%-%date:~4,2%-%date:~7,2%_%time:~0,2%-%time:~3,2%-%time:~6,2%   (may need adjustment depending on your Windows Region settings).  Also, the tokens value may need to be changed to grab the PID from tasklist output.  Finally, the %~dp0 folder where the batch file lives cannot contain any spaces.  Run the batch file As Administrator.

Answer (score 0):

For GUI based tools like `jconsole`, please enable **JMX support** in `tomcat`, and connect via JMX.

For the command line tools, such as `jps`, `jstat`, please run following in an admin console. Note: better add `psexec` path and `%JAVA_HOME%\bin` into `PATH` env.

```hs
psexec -S cmd.exe
```

After we get a new `console`, we can run the `jps`, `jstat` or other tools to `"debug"` the `tomcat` running as windows service using local system account.

```hs
e:\sde\PSTools>jps
7408 Jps

e:\sde\PSTools>psexec -s cmd

PsExec v2.2 - Execute processes remotely
Copyright (C) 2001-2016 Mark Russinovich
Sysinternals - www.sysinternals.com


Microsoft Windows [Version 6.2.9200]
(c) 2012 Microsoft Corporation. All rights reserved.

C:\windows\system32>jps
9792 Jps
8812

C:\windows\system32>jstat -gc 8812
 S0C    S1C    S0U    S1U      EC       EU        OC         OU       MC     MU    CCSC   CCSU   YGC     YGCT    FGC    FGCT     G
CT
10752.0 10752.0  0.0   10744.3 65536.0  21751.1   175104.0    3730.9   17792.0 17138.5 2176.0 1974.8      1    0.034   0      0.00
0    0.034
```