# Javac not recognised

Tags: batch-file

I tried typing the name of the bat file (makejar.bat) from the containing direcory from the command line. It gives several errors all containing "'javac' is not recognised as an internal or external command."

Comment: could you show us the contents of the .bat file in question?

Comment: Is your java CLASSPATH set?

Comment: That suggests that your `bat` file contains errors.

Comment: I don't know @user65439

Comment: how do I do that? @Tim Cooper / user65439

Comment: possible duplicate of [How can I set the PATH variable for javac so I can manually compile my .java works?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2079635/how-can-i-set-the-path-variable-for-javac-so-i-can-manually-compile-my-java-wor)

Comment: Check how to add the environment variable [here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/environment/paths.html), and then it will work (if there aren't more errors).

Comment: followed instructions for adding the environment variable- still get same errors @Juan

Comment: @bluesh34 keep in mind you may need to restart the machine. And another important question have you installed JDK? Show us the .bat content if possible

Comment: What happens if you type the following into the command prompt: java -version

Comment: tried repeating those instructions and it works now, so must have done something wrong first time- thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This sounds like a java class path problem.

You can find the instructions to set the java CLASSPATH on the following [Oracle web page](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/environment/paths.html).

Comment: followed these instructions for adding the environment variable- still get same errors

Comment: What happens if you type the following into the command prompt: java -version

Comment: Actually, I just repeated the instructions and it works, so maybe I did something wrong first time

Answer (score 1):

I suppose you are working on Windows, so make sure that your environment variables are properly set:

```
JAVA_HOME - points to a proper JDK installation
PATH - contains a references to JAVA_HOME, something like: **PATH;%JAVA_HOME%\bin**
```

This should do it! Make sure to restart the command line you are using after making changes to environment variables.

You can see how to set/add environment variables on windows [here](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/310519).

Answer (score 0):

On CMD--> type--> PATH="c:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_144\bin";
and then check java path by type "java -version" on cmd
and also check on YouTube : -https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=mzAAmJj-W6w

Comment: A link to an outside source is not the same as an answer. Please consider adding key details from the video to your answer.