# Command Prompt: java file not found

Tags: java, command-prompt

The file name is BookDemo.java and I compiled it like this: `javac bookpack\BookDemo.java`

This is my block of code:

```
package bookpack;  

class Book {  
private String title;  
private String author;  
private int pubDate;  

Book(String t, String a, int d) {  
title = t;  
author = a;  
pubDate = d;  
}  

void show() {  
System.out.println(title);  
System.out.println(author);  
System.out.println(pubDate); 
System.out.println(); 
  }  
}  

class BookDemo {  
public static void main(String args[]) {  
Book books[] = new Book[5];  

books[0] = new Book("Java: A Beginner's Guide", 
                    "Schildt", 2011);  
books[1] = new Book("Java: The Complete Reference", 
                    "Schildt", 2011); 
books[2] = new Book("The Art of Java", 
                    "Schildt and Holmes", 2003); 
books[3] = new Book("Red Storm Rising", 
                     "Clancy", 1986);  
books[4] = new Book("On the Road", 
                    "Kerouac", 1955);  

for(int i=0; i < books.length; i++) books[i].show();  
   } 
}
```

The output is this:
 `javac: file not found:bookpack\BookDemo.java                                                         Usage: javac <options> <source files>
use -help for a list of possible options`

How can you fix this so that the code will execute? Thank you for your help!!!

Comment: so how are you trying to run java?  What is the command ?

Comment: Can you include the entire input and output?  This sounds like it might be an issue with your PATH.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to execute a java .class from the command line](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1279542/how-to-execute-a-java-class-from-the-command-line)

Comment: Post the command to run it. It might be that the name isn't fully qualified since it's in a package. Run it with java bookpack.BookDemo from the bookpack folder.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The compile never completed because `javac` could not successfully find your `.java` file. Try putting in the entire path to the file. For example, if the file is in `C:\Users\James\bookpack\BookDemo.java`, try running `javac "C:\Users\James\bookpack\BookDemo.java"`.

After the compilation is complete, you would run it with `java "C:\Users\James\bookpack\BookDemo"`.

Comment: When I do this, it says that "'javac' is recognized as an internal or external command, operable or batch files"

Comment: Look into adding Java to your path environment variable.

Answer (score 0):

To run program you must try this command:

```
java bookpack.BookDemo
```

While running program, you need to specify the class containing `main()`.

Make sure that cmd/termincal location is like e.g.

```
D:\
|
`+-your-folder(cmd here)
    |
    `+-bookpack
```

Answer (score 0):

I placed your code in file **BookDemo.java** inside directory **C:\Java\new**

And run commands below:

> C:\Java\new>javac -version javac 1.7.0_40
>
> C:\Java\new>javac -d . BookDemo.java
>
> C:\Java\new>java bookpack.BookDemo Java: A Beginner's Guide Schildt
>   2011
>
> Java: The Complete Reference Schildt 2011
>
> The Art of Java Schildt and Holmes 2003
>
> Red Storm Rising Clancy 1986
>
> On the Road Kerouac 1955
>
> C:\Java\new>

The command :

> javac -version

for checking the **javac** already on your **PATH**
.If it failure check the post [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2079635/how-can-i-set-the-path-variable-for-javac-so-i-can-manually-compile-my-java-wor)