# kill -3 to get java thread dump

Tags: java, multithreading, thread-dump

I am using `kill -3` command to see the JVM's thread dump in unix. But where can I find the output of this `kill` command? I am lost!!

Comment: Which process are you killing? Is it a J2EE app server? If it's the case you should find the stack trace in the standard out.

Comment: I am killing a process that runs the java class

Comment: Should'nt that write the thread dump on the console. since the java class has console as std out

Comment: In my case (a Spring Boot application running on CentOS 7), the thread dump was logged to `/var/log/messages`.

Answer (score 218, accepted):

You could alternatively use jstack (Included with JDK) to take a thread dump and write the output wherever you want. Is that not available in a unix environment?

```
jstack PID > outfile
```

Comment: Thanks for that.Absolutely!! Yes I can use this. jstack PID > outfile will output the thread dump at that particular period of time. Isn't it?

Comment: Yes - at the point in time it is run. You can also specify -l (lowercase L) for a long listing that prints additional lock information

Comment: Until the jstack command fails consistently due to "Unable to deduce type of thread from address" ;-(

Comment: If you're seeing that error, I suggest taking it up with your vendor. A quick search shows, for example, there is an open bug in RHEL regarding this error and openjdk...

Comment: It's worth noting that jstack requires the JDK.  If you're running apps on a server that only has the JRE installed, you'll need to find another means for thread dumping.

Comment: Here is how to use jstack to obtain thread dump of a process running under different user, like windows service: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1197912/cant-debug-java-windows-services-with-jhat-jps-jstack/47723393#47723393

Comment: I found this didn't result in the dump being sent to the STDOUT of jstack but the STDOUT of the java process instead, possibly because withtout the `-F` flag the request failed, then adding the `-F` may have caused the process to do this.

Answer (score 48):

The thread dump is written to the system out of the VM on which you executed the `kill -3`.  If you are redirecting the console output of the JVM to a file, the thread dump will be in that file.  If the JVM is running in an open console, then the thread dump will be displayed in its console.

Comment: There is a way to redirect JVM thread dump output to separate file. See in my answer.

Answer (score 35):

There is a way to redirect JVM thread dump output on break signal to separate file with [LogVMOutput diagnostic option](http://stas-blogspot.blogspot.com/2011/07/most-complete-list-of-xx-options-for.html#LogVMOutput):

```
-XX:+UnlockDiagnosticVMOptions -XX:+LogVMOutput -XX:LogFile=jvm.log
```

Comment: Technically this doesn't "redirect" the thread dump output. It turns on JVM logging into jvm.log (which includes thread dump output) but kill -QUIT will still dump to the process's stdout (aswell).

Upvoted for the description of obscure JVM options :)

Answer (score 30):

With Java 8 in picture, `jcmd` is the preferred approach.

```
jcmd <PID> Thread.print
```

Following is the snippet from [Oracle documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/guides/troubleshoot/tooldescr016.html) :

The release of JDK 8 introduced Java Mission Control, Java Flight Recorder, and jcmd utility for diagnosing problems with JVM and Java applications. **It is suggested to use the latest utility, jcmd instead of the previous jstack utility for enhanced diagnostics and reduced performance overhead.**

However, shipping this with the application may be licensing implications which I am not sure.

Comment: Unfortunately `jcmd` fails to connect to windows service process with `com.sun.tools.attach.AttachNotSupportedException: Insufficient memory or insufficient privileges to attach` while `jstack -F` succeeds: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1197912/cant-debug-java-windows-services-with-jhat-jps-jstack/47723393#47723393

Comment: You need to run jcmd <pid> Thread.dump under the same user as java process has, otherwise your connections will be dropped. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25438983/com-sun-tools-attach-attachnotsupportedexception-unable-to-open-socket-file-ta

Answer (score 14):

In the same location where the JVM's stdout is placed. If you have a Tomcat server, this will be the `catalina_(date).out` file.

Answer (score 9):

When using kill -3 one should see the thread dump in the standard output. Most of the application servers write the standard output to a separate file. You should find it there when using kill -3. There are multiple ways of getting thread dumps:

- `kill -3 <PID>`: Gives output to  standard output.
- If one has access to the console window where server is running, one can use <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Break</kbd> combination of keys to generate the stack trace on STDOUT.
- For hotspot VM's we can also use `jstack` command to generate a thread dump. It’s a part of the JDK. Syntax is as follows:

  ```
  Usage:

  jstack [-l] <pid> (to connect to running process)
  jstack -F [-m] [-l] <pid>(to connect to a hung process)

   - For JRockit JVM we can use JRCMD command which comes with JDK Syntax: 
     jrcmd <jrockit pid> [<command> [<arguments>]] [-l] [-f file] [-p] -h]
  ```

Comment: I'm having trouble using Kill -3 <PID>. It works ok but kills the process also after writing thread dump to console. Is it supposed to do that?

Comment: @Ashley - no `kill -3 <PID>` shouldn't kill the JVM. What type of Java app are you looking at?

Answer (score 2):

In Jboss you can perform the following

```
nohup $JBOSS_HOME/bin/run.sh -c  yourinstancename $JBOSS_OPTS >> console-$(date +%Y%m%d).out  2>&1 < /dev/null &
kill -3 <java_pid>
```

This will redirect your output/threadump to the file console specified in the above command.

Answer (score 2):

1. Find the process id [PS ID]
2. Execute jcmd [PS ID] Thread.print

Answer (score 2):

Steps that you should follow if you want the thread dump of your StandAlone Java Process

**Step 1:** Get the Process ID for the shell script calling the java program

```
linux$ ps -aef | grep "runABCD"

user1  **8535**  4369   0   Mar 25 ?           0:00 /bin/csh /home/user1/runABCD.sh

user1 17796 17372   0 08:15:41 pts/49      0:00 grep runABCD
```

**Step 2:** Get the Process ID for the Child  which was Invoked by the runABCD. Use the above PID to get the childs.

```
linux$ ps -aef | grep **8535**

user1  **8536**  8535   0   Mar 25 ?         126:38 /apps/java/jdk/sun4/SunOS5/1.6.0_16/bin/java -cp /home/user1/XYZServer

user1  8535  4369   0   Mar 25 ?           0:00 /bin/csh /home/user1/runABCD.sh

user1 17977 17372   0 08:15:49 pts/49      0:00 grep 8535
```

**Step 3:** Get the JSTACK for the particular process. Get the Process id of your XYSServer process. i.e. 8536

```
linux$ jstack **8536** > threadDump.log
```

Answer (score 0):

For example， if you use tomcat.
The log possible will stay at
`[tomcat dir]/logs/catalina.out`