# How to get all currently running threads in a batch file in java?

Tags: java, multithreading

How can I get all currently running threads in a batch file in java?

Comment: See this post.

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1323408/get-a-list-of-all-threads-currently-running-in-java

Possible dup.

Comment: In batch file? Linux, bash, or what? Or is it really a Java question? Do you want to do it inside your java code?

Comment: yes in windows and yeah I want to do it in my java code

Comment: @AlecHenderson_v1.00 I have already tried this but it reads all the running threads in system but not in the batch file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can get running threads like this:

```
Set<Thread> threadSet = Thread.getAllStackTraces().keySet();
```

Then output the information you need of each thread. Once donecreate a batch file which calls your java file using: `java ProgrammName`

Answer (score 0):

The top rated answer to this question: [kill -3 to get java thread dump](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4876274/kill-3-to-get-java-thread-dump) suggests using jstack. Run this on the command line using the pid (from task manager) and redirect the output to a file. Then read it with your batch file.

For example:

```
jstack -l 5980 > threaddump.txt
```