# Tomcat thread dump

Tags: java, tomcat, permgen, thread-dump

Is there away to take **a thread dump** from Tomcat? I would like to monitor the threads running in Tomcat at a certain point in time.

**Note:** I was doing that on Web logic but i don't know how it can be done on Tomcat.

Answer (score 41, accepted):

If you use Linux, you can send a kill -3 [pid of your tomcat] and it will dump all current threads in the catalina.out.

Comment: I'd like to add that it'll likely be `catalina.out`

Comment: Good addition indeed.

Comment: Better answer here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4876274/kill-3-to-get-java-thread-dump

Comment: Note you need sudo access for this.

Answer (score 9):

There is a simple way to monitor tomcat threads and do a dump. 
Start tomcat with the folowing java options :

```
-Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.port=<some free port>
-Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.ssl=false
-Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.authenticate=false
```

After the tomcat is restarted you can simply start jconsole (part of jdk) or visualvm and create a new jmx connection to the port you have chosen above.
In both tools you also have an option to take a dump ;)

!!!But do that only in closed/secured environment - since there is no authentication set.!!!

Answer (score 5):

add java melody to your server
https://code.google.com/p/javamelody/

it give you a lot of info including threads in runtime

Answer (score 2):

The following steps should help you get the current Java threads running and analyze them:

1. Download IBM JCA which is a nice thread dump analyzer from [IBM Thread & Dump Monitor Analyzer](ftp://public.dhe.ibm.com/software/websphere/appserv/support/tools/jca/jca451.jar)
2. Execute the following to get the Tomcat threads dump: `root@localhost:~# sudo -u $TOMCAT_USER $JAVA_HOME/bin/jstack -J-d64 -l $(ps aux | grep '[c]atalina' | awk '{print $2}') > ~/threads.log`
3. Open the threads dump with [IBM Thread & Dump Monitor Analyzer](ftp://public.dhe.ibm.com/software/websphere/appserv/support/tools/jca/jca451.jar)

**Note:** Replace `$JAVA_HOME` with your path to your current JDK, `$TOMCAT_USER` with the user running Tomcat; if you pass the wrong user or even using root you will get an error like this:

```
3047: well-known file is not secure
```

Answer (score 0):

Please try netbeans profiler to profile any web applications.

https://profiler.netbeans.org/

http://wiki.netbeans.org/FaqProfilerAttachRemoteServer