# Get Unix Thread Dump

Tags: java, linux, unix

I am trying to get a unix (solaris and linux) thread dump on a java application.

1) When the java application is a tomcat web application,
using kill -3 , the dump goes to the catalina.out file, as this is standard output.
kill -3 pid > td.out does not work.

2) For another spring standalone java application, how do I find the standard output for it.
I have used:
kill -3 pid, and I have checked in my application logs, and I cannot find anything.

Please advise how I can determine standard output for the java application  and see the thread dump.

Thanks,
B.

Answer (score 4):

If you're using OpenJDK or Sun JDK 6 or later, try the jstack command in the bin folder. This is useful when redirecting standard out to a file is problematic for some reason. Execute the following, passing in the Java process ID:

```
jstack -l JAVA_PID > jstack.out
```

Comment: On the unix machine, I don't have access to jdk, only a jre 1.6. Hence I am using kill -3 pid or kill -QUIT pid.

Comment: I found this:

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4876274/kill-3-to-get-java-thread-dump?rq=1

Add the following to java program, this will redirect jvm stuff to a file
-XX:+UnlockDiagnosticVMOptions -XX:+LogVMOutput -XX:LogFile=jvm.log

This works but have to change java arguments.

Answer (score 0):

Try using Process

```
Process p = null;
String cmd[] = {"bash","-c","ps -C java | awk '{ print $1; }' | sed -n '2{p;q;}'"};
try
{
p = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(cmd);
try
{
p.waitFor();
System.out.println("Executed Successfully");
}catch(Exception e)
 {
e.printStackTrace();
}

}catch(Exception e)
{
e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Then read the line by BufferReader and use the above function to kill and output the same

Explanation for the command :

```
ps -C java | awk '{ print $1; }' | sed -n '2{p;q;}'
```

" ps -C ProcessName " tells the process if its running with pid, here Java is used as ProcessName

" awk '{ print $1; }' " outputs the 1st row of the output

" sed -n '2{p;q;} " to display the 2nd column