# How do you find the stack trace of a JavaScript Promise that never resolves?

Tags: javascript, node.js, jasmine

I've written an automated test in [Jasmine](https://jasmine.github.io/pages/getting_started.html) that tests my asynchronous code. Somewhere in my code, a `Promise` fails to resolve/reject and Jasmine errors with a timeout:

```
  Message:
    Error: Timeout - Async function did not complete within 5000ms (set by jasmine.DEFAULT_TIMEOUT_INTERVAL)
  Stack:
        at <Jasmine>
        at listOnTimeout (node:internal/timers:573:17)
        at processTimers (node:internal/timers:514:7)
```

It's not a matter of giving the promise more time. Increasing the timeout has the same effect but with a longer delay.

Unfortunately, that stack trace doesn't lead me to the source of the problem. It's a stack trace to the Jasmine code that interrupted my test, not the part of my code that was waiting to resolve. How do I see the latter?

I'm not sure how much Jasmine factors into a potential solution. For example, [Java has ways to see all the threads in a program.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4876274/kill-3-to-get-java-thread-dump) Does Node.JS have something similar? Is there a library or node.js setting that makes promises more verbose?

I'm using node v20.10.0.

Comment: How many promises do you have in your code? There are many ways a `Promise` can never resolve. You can pass all of your individual promises to `Promise.race()` with a `Promise` that will fulfill 1 second, or less, before your test application assertion or otherwise halts execution.

Comment: @guest271314 About 150 all throughout the project. I don't have an easy way to collected them into an array I can pass into `race()`.

Comment: If there is nothing that resolves the promise, there is nothing to see… The code that is waiting never runs, so you can't get a stack trace from it.

Comment: That's manageable to wrap in `Promise.all()` to filter your results. There's `--trace-promises` on `node` nightly v22.0.0-nightly202403032a70831d27 though that isn't documented on the command line documentation. You'll have to find release notes. It doesn't sound like an exception, rather an arbitrary timer you have set using third-party code.

Comment: Not sure if you might be able to do something crazy with [async hooks](https://nodejs.org/api/async_hooks.html) and [finalisation registries](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/FinalizationRegistry) to find promises that get garbage-collected without being settled, but you'd likely get a lot of false positives and would need to put quite some effort into organising them into a readable "stack trace" of the function calls that led to the deepest unresolved promise…

Comment: @guest271314 dang. [That's a pretty recent addition](https://github.com/nodejs/node/blob/main/doc/changelogs/CHANGELOG_V21.md).

Comment: @DanielKaplan _"I don't have an easy way to collected them into an array I can pass into race()"_ What I mean is for each of your `Promise` constructors or `async` functions and/or `await`, create a `Promise.race([<setTimeout,resolve,1 second before your real Promise>, <your real Promise>])`. _"dang. That's a pretty recent addition."_ I only run `node` nightly, extracted from the archive without the rest of the content of the archive, latest `deno`, `bun`, `tjs`, and `qjs` (from quickjs-ng that txiki.js depends on), Chromium Dev Channel and Firefox Nightly which I update every couple of days.

Comment: @guest271314 "What I meant is for each of your Promise constructors..." Hm. Perhaps I should create a configurable `PromiseWithTimeout` class they all use. `I only run node nightly` Still, that flag seems new to v21 if I'm reading that changelog correctly.

Comment: @DanielKaplan That should work. That's something you can manage, and you'll narrow down or pinpoint the line number, etc. that you `resolve()`. I download and extract `node` from the nightly release archive https://gist.github.com/guest271314/012441b6809f60ea542b690660ee8e0d#file-fetch_node-js every day or so, the same with the rest of the JavaScript engines, runtimes and browsers I test and experiment with.

Comment: @Bergi "The code that is waiting never runs, so you can't get a stack trace from it." True, but the pending Promise is running; a stack trace to it would be highly informative. It would tell me which of my many `Promise`s cause the problem and the path the code took to get there.

Comment: @DanielKaplan Technically a promise isn't "running", at best the `async` function that created it is. And even that got suspended when it started waiting. Using the async hooks I mentioned you may be able to get a trace for all function calls whose execution is currently suspended.