# how to generate websphere thread dump without wsadmin on windows server

Tags: windows, websphere-7, thread-dump

I have websphere application server v 7 over windows server and I want to generate thread dumps because i have thread hungs, but when I try to get the java cores with wsadmin appears an error, so I want to generate java core files like linux using kill -3 .

Is there something like this in Windows server ?.

Answer (score 1):

Like ObiWanKenobi mentioned, your best bet would probably be through the deployment manager administrative console.  From IBM's support site:

Set the com.ibm.websphere.threadmonitor.dump.java property to true:

Application Servers:

1. From the administrative console, click Servers > Application Servers > server_name.
2. Under Server Infrastructure, click Administration > Custom Properties.
3. Click New and add the following property:

Name: com.ibm.websphere.threadmonitor.dump.java

Value: true

4. Click Apply.
5. Click OK and save the configuration changes.
6. Restart the Application Server for the changes to take effect.

Node Agent:

1. From the administrative console, click System Administration > Node Agents > nodeagent.
2. Under Additional Properties, click Administration Services
3. Under Additional Properties, click Custom Properties
4. Click New and add the following property:

Name: com.ibm.websphere.threadmonitor.dump.java

Value: true

5. Click Apply.
6. Click OK and save the configuration changes.
7. Restart the Node Agent for the changes to take effect.

Answer (score 0):

In short, there is no good answer.

The closest would be to use something like SendSignal.  See the [Can I send a ctrl-C (SIGINT) to an application on Windows?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/813086/can-i-send-a-ctrl-c-sigint-to-an-application-on-windows) question for more information.  Unfortunately, SendSignal doesn't work reliably on all versions of Windows (see my [Send ctrl-break to java process on 64-bit Windows ala sendsignal on 32-bit](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6129790/send-ctrl-break-to-java-process-on-64-bit-windows-ala-sendsignal-on-32-bit) question).

If you're willing to write some custom code, you could write a Java program that uses the [attach API](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSYKE2_7.0.0/com.ibm.java.aix.70.doc/user/attachapi.html) to load a Java agent that calls the [Dump API](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSYKE2_7.0.0/com.ibm.java.api.70.doc/com.ibm.jvm.ras/com/ibm/jvm/Dump.html).  (I suspect that [IBM Support Assistant](https://www-01.ibm.com/software/support/isa/) has this capability built-in, but it's been too long since I tried to be authoritative on this point.)

Answer (score 0):

You can make the JVM to do a thread dump when there are 'hung' threads messages in the SystemOut.log:
Add com.ibm.websphere.threadmonitor.dump.java=true under JVM's Administration > Custom Properties.