# windows batch file, if else condition to check if task exist

Tags: windows, batch-file

Current I have this set of codes in a TEST.bat

```
@echo off
echo HELLO
pause
```

What I want to do is...

1) I play TEST.bat, it shows "HELLO" on a command prompt (Correct)
2) I play again, another windows pop up "HELLO" on a command prompt (correct behavior but.. )

Is it possible to do this

```
If(cmd.exe is running)
{
 close it
 play TEST.BAT
}
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [how to kill all batch files except the one currently running](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12024149/how-to-kill-all-batch-files-except-the-one-currently-running)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In theory you can just fire the [taskkill command](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb491009.aspx) regardless if the task is running or not:

```
taskkill /f /im sometask.exe
```

If you really need to figure out if a task is running, you can do

```
tasklist | find "your task's name"
```

If afterwards %errorlevel% is 1, the task name was not found.