# How to find the process id of a running Java process on Windows? And how to kill the process alone?

Tags: java, windows, process-management

I want to kill the particular Java process in Windows, like in Linux (`ps -aux` to get processid and then `kill processid` to kill the process).

Comment: check following
[enter link description here][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8435952/how-to-get-pid-from-command-line-filtered-by-username-and-imagename

Answer (score 56, accepted):

You can use the `jps` utility that is [included in the JDK](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/tools/jps.html#GUID-6EB65B96-F9DD-4356-B825-6146E9EEC81E) to find the process id of a Java process. The output will show you the name of the executable JAR file or the name of the main class.

Then use the Windows task manager to terminate the process. If you want to do it on the command line, use

```
TASKKILL /PID %PID%
```

Comment: `jps` tool is now included in **JDK/bin** directory. I also recommend to use `-l` option, which outputs the full package name for the application's main class, which might be helpful.

Comment: jps is not part of the JRE 1.8 on Windows.

Comment: and it's not allowed to redistribute jps.exe outside of bundled JDK - if you get this fancy idea like myself :( - therefore WMIC solution below is the real winner for me

Answer (score 19):

You can also find the PID of a java program with the task manager. You enable the **PID** and **Command Line** columns `View -> Select Columns` and are then able to find the right process.

Your result will be something like this :
[image]

Comment: Your Windows Task Manager window is in German, but your it show full answer: We may find java process on list, then we have its PID number and in `Command line` (here on image _Befehlszeile_) we see full command, which helps us to discriminate which _java_ process to kill.

Comment: To edit column list, just right-click on any column header (in Details tab) and choose `Select column` option.

Answer (score 13):

This will work even when there are multiple instance of jar is running

```
wmic Path win32_process Where "CommandLine Like '%yourname.jar%'" Call Terminate
```

Answer (score 12):

After setting the path of your jdk use `JPS`.Then You can eaisly kill it by Task Manager
`JPS` will give you all java processes

Comment: Feel free to ask if you have any ambiguity :)

Comment: Please accept the answer if it helps :) see http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/23138/how-to-accept-the-answer-on-stack-overflow

Answer (score 5):

In windows, we can use the PowerShell to list the java running process. Then using the process id we can kill the process. Please find the below commands that needs to be executed in the PowerShell.

**To list the Java Process.**

```
ps | Where-Object -Property ProcessName -EQ -Value 'Java'
```

**To kill the java process with specific id.**

```
Stop-Process <PID>
```

The above approach worked for me.

Answer (score 2):

The solution I found is very simple. Use Window's WMIC & Java's Runtime to locate & kill the process.

Part 1: You need to put some sort of identifier into your app's startup command line. E.g. something like:

```
String id = "com.domain.app";
```

Part 2: When you run your app, make sure to include the string. Let's say you start it from within Java, do the following:

```
Runtime.getRuntime().exec(
   "C:\...\javaw.exe -cp ... -Dwhatever=" + id + " com.domain.app.Main"
);
```

Part 3: To kill the process, use Window's WMIC. Just make sure you app was started containing your id from above:

```
Runtime.getRuntime().exec(
  "wmic process Where \"CommandLine Like '%" + id + "%'\" Call Terminate"
);
```

Answer (score 1):

In windows XP and later, there's a command: **tasklist** that lists all process id's.

For killing a process in Windows, see:

[Really killing a process in Windows | Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49990/92063)

You can execute OS-commands in Java by:

```
Runtime.getRuntime().exec("your command here");
```

If you need to handle the output of a command, see example: [using Runtime.exec() in Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1319286/using-runtime-exec-in-java)

Answer (score 1):

1. Open Git Bash
2. Type `ps -ef | grep java`
3. Find the `pid` of running jdk
4. `kill -9 [pid]`

Answer (score 0):

This is specific to Windows.
I was facing the same issue where I have to kill one specific java program using taskkill. When I run the java program, tasklist was showing the same program with Image name set as java.exe.
But killing it using `taskkill /F java.exe` will stop all other java applications other than intended one which is not required.

So I run the same java program using:

```
start "MyProgramName" java java-program..
```

Here start command will open a new window and run the java program with window's title set to MyProgramName.

Now to kill this java-program use the following taskkill command:

```
taskkill /fi "MyProgramName"
```

Your Java program will be killed only. Rest will be unaffected.

Comment: taskkill doesn't work: error: search filter is not recognized (something about it). But thanks for `start "MyProgramName"`

Comment: taskkill /fi "WINDOWTITLE eq MyProgramName" works just fine.