# How to kill a task in batch?

Tags: windows, batch-file, task

I am having problems with the `taskkill` in batch, I am trying to kill a vbscript that is in sleep for an x amount of seconds.
So basically I want to kill this task: 
https://i.stack.imgur.com/rxgAL.png

But I somehow seem to get it wrong, I have no clue what part of the task I have to write in the `taskkill x`

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This will kill it without knowing the `pid`, however it will kill ***all*** instances of `wscript.exe`.

```
TASKKILL /F /IM wscript.exe
```

Comment: I dont run any other wscript files, so I think that would be fine... Does windows by default run any wscripts? Or does any programs...? Like, I don't want it to kill something it shouldn't

Answer (score 2):

From the task manager top menu, select to show the `Process ID` for this running process.

Then on command prompt,

```
  taskkill /pid 1234
```

Where 1234 id the `Process ID` you want to kill.

Comment: Does it always have the same ID..?
And how do I find the ID...? xD

Comment: See this [post](http://stackoverflow.com/q/8435952/833786) to look for process ID using command line

Comment: So, I cant possibly make a batch file kill a specific task? 
And there is no way to 'get task' or something...?

Or maybe just a way to cancel and close a vbscript from its' sleep...? :)'

Comment: what does this script do and why do you want to kill it?

Comment: I want to kill it/cancel a sleeping vbscript for another, new/updated one to replace it.

I am making an Automatic Shutdown batch (oh how original), I have a vbscript showing 5 minutes before shutdown, asking if you want to cancel - but if I set the shutdown, decide to chance the time (in a controlpanel), the vbscript from the 'old' shutdown is still in sleep mode, so both scripts will be showing.

Now back on track...
Though, I got this:
for /f "tokens=2" %%a in ('tasklist^|find /i "wscript.exe"') do (set pid=%%a)
^ How do I get that to get a specific wscript, my wscript, and not any other?

Answer (score 2):

VBScripts do have a timeout parameter - see `cscript /?`.

```
taskkill /im wscript.exe /im cscript.exe /f
```

will kill all running vbscripts.

If you want to be particular how do you tell the running scripts apart.