# Using PsExec in a Windows Service

Tags: c#, windows-services, psexec

I have created a Windows Service using C# which performs variance network maintenance tasks for me.  One of the tasks is defraging machines remotely and for some of my older boxes I found the only way to do this was using psexec with defrag.exe.  The code works fine when I simply run my C# code, however when I covert it into a Windows Service it does the defraging using the Win32_Volume table fine but it seems to get hung up when attempting to use PsExec to defrag the XP machines.

I guess my questions is, are there any known errors with using PsExec within a Windows Service?  If so are there any suggestions for a different method I can use?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

psexec issues a software licence agreement dialog the first time it is run as a given user, so that could be your problem if the service is running as some other user.

You can suppress this by adding the parameter

```
/accepteula
```

This could be your problem, though obviously I can't be sure!

Comment: I am still having a problem with this, I get farther along in the code now but it appear there is some sort of permissions problem running defrag.exe on a remote machine with PsExec.  I have tried entering the username and password of an account with sufficient privileges but it doesn't seem to help.  Any ideas??

Comment: It seems like my continued problems are less to do with PsExec and more to do with the Windows Service because the task works in my C# code but gives me an exit code of 6 (handle is invalid) in my windows service...I am running the process with an account that does have admin rights on the machines in question...any ideas??