# Redirect output of command in for loop of batch script

Tags: batch-file, for-loop, cmd, io-redirection

```
...
for /F %%F in ('dir /B %* 2> nul') do (
...
```

What I'm attempting to do here is discard the err output of the command (and loop over the stdout output). However, it complains:

```
2> was unexpected at this time.
```

Is this some way to achieve this?

Answer (score 36, accepted):

in this case you need to escape the > like this

```
for /F %%F in ('dir /B %* 2^> nul') do (
```

Comment: Microsoft uses an intern to implement the command shell and we have to live with it for the rest of our lives...

Comment: Saved my day, Mr. Guggisberg :). I'd like to add: If you want to redirect stderr to stdout, by using 2>&1, you need to escape the & too.

Answer (score -6):

I believe you need a delimiting space between the "2" and the ">". Without that delimiter my dir test output still displayed on the screen. Furthermore, I believe that by sending the output of the dir command to null will not provide any data back for the set to process.

Comment: No. Changing `2>` to `2 >` would redirect STDOUT instead of STDERR, thus preventing the processing of the actual directory listing. As @RGuggisberg correctly pointed out, the redirection operator must be escaped in the nested command.