# Server certificate verification failed: issuer is not trusted

Tags: svn, ant

I am getting below error when running a target of ANT script. Error message saying that "server certificate verification is failed". Please help how to remove this problem. I am working in Windows XP.

```
C:\apache-ant-1.8.1>ant checkout
Buildfile: C:\Program Files\Java\apache-ant-1.8.1\build.xml

checkout:
[svn] Using command line interface
Svn : Checking out a working copy from a repository :
co -r HEAD https://col.../trunk C:\ant-1.8.1\Test_Checkout 
--username 69 --password *******--non-interactive
svn: PROPFIND request failed on '/svn/asia-pac-financials/trunk'
svn: PROPFIND of '/sv.../trunk': 
Server certificate verification failed: 
issuer is not trusted (https://col....com)

BUILD FAILED
C:\apache-ant-1.8.1\build.xml:16: Can't checkout

Total time: 3 seconds
```

Answer (score 158, accepted):

can you try to run `svn checkout` once manually to your URL `https://yoururl/trunk C:\ant-1.8.1\Test_Checkout` using command line
and accept certificate.

Or as @AndrewSpear says below

Rather than checking out manually run `svn list https://your.repository.url` from Terminal (Mac) / Command Line (Win) to get the option to accept the certificate permanently

svn will ask you for confirmation. accept it permanently.

After that this should work for subsequent requests from ant script.

Comment: I added also a example script for PHP here: http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.svn-auth-set-parameter.php#104300 for the same problem.

Comment: Rather than checking out manually I just run `svn list https://your.repository.url` from Terminal (Mac) / Command Line (Win) to get the option to accept the certificate permanently.

Comment: On OS X I needed to use sudo with the svn list command, otherwise selecting (p)ermanent didn't seem to work.

Comment: I replaced **svn**://repos.server.url with **https**://repos.server.url, only than I got asked to accept the SSL certificate.

Answer (score 56):

Run "svn help commit" to all available options. You will see that there is one option responsible for accepting server certificates:

`--trust-server-cert`      : accept unknown SSL server certificates without
                           prompting (but only with `--non-interactive`)

Add it to your svn command arguments and you will not need to run svn manually to accept it permanently.

Comment: This is the best solution for automated scripts, which won't normally have the luxury of the steps outlined in the accepted answer. It should be noted though that blindly accepting SSL certs basically defeats the entire purpose of SSL, and thus can open you up to MitM attacks.

Comment: How can I add this option, if I use maven scm plugin?

Comment: this doesn't work if server sends you certificate with hostname value which differs from actual server hostname

Comment: I have the same problem as Andrey: The validation still fails if the name doesn't match.

Comment: Updated my certs this evening on our SVN server and got this. The cert is trusted per the browser. Why is the SVN client freaking out all of a sudden? Used your trick to solve my issue.

Comment: --trust-server-cert is deprecated now, and doesn't work as it used to. The equivalent parameter is `--trust-server-cert-failures=unknown-ca,cn-mismatch,expired,not-yet-valid,other`. See http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.7/svn.ref.svn.c.commit.html

Comment: @cedd comment worked for me although I can't find any official documentation about it. I did find https://github.com/MicrosoftDocs/vsts-docs/issues/3681 but that's not from Subversion.

Answer (score 15):

I wouldn't use:

```
svn checkout
```

just to authorizes the server authentication, I rather use:

```
svn list https://your.repository.url
```

which will ask you to do the authentication as well.

If this is needed to get authorization to a user that can't login, run:

```
sudo -u username svn list https://your.repository.url
```

Comment: This successfully helped me install svn on El Capitan.

Answer (score 3):

If you are using svn with Jenkins on a Windows Server, you must accept https certificate using the same Jenkins's Windows service user.
So , if your Jenkins service runs as "MYSERVER\Administrator", you must use this  command before all others, only one time of course :

**runas /user:MYSERVER\Administrator "svn --username user --password password list https://myserver/svn/REPO "**

svn asks you to accept the certificate and **stores it in the right path**.

After this you'll be able to use svn in jenkins job directly in a Windows batch command step.

Comment: If you're running as the default Windows NT service user (Local System Account i.e. "nt authority\system"), then you'll need to use psexec to open a cmd.exe as this Windows user  and run an interactive svn.exe command like
"svn --username yourSvnUser list yourSvnUrl"
so that you can accept the SVN server's SSL certificate.  Afterwards, you can run "svn auth" to check the stored credentials cache.
See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77528/how-do-you-run-cmd-exe-under-the-local-system-account/78691#78691

Answer (score 2):

As noted in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3147660/server-certificate-verification-failed-issuer-is-not-trusted#comment98971607_5340408) comment (which of course I missed when trying to solve this issue) the command line options to ignore certificate verification issues have changed in [Subversion 1.9](https://subversion.apache.org/docs/release-notes/1.9#svn-trust) and you should now use `--trust-server-cert-failures`.

Example:

```
--non-interactive --trust-server-cert-failures unknown-ca,cn-mismatch,expired,not-yet-valid,other
```

Here is the relevant inline help from svn 1.13:

> --trust-server-cert      : deprecated; same as
> --trust-server-cert-failures=unknown-ca

> --trust-server-cert-failures ARG : with --non-interactive, accept SSL server
> certificates with failures; ARG is comma-separated
> list of 'unknown-ca' (Unknown Authority),
> 'cn-mismatch' (Hostname mismatch), 'expired'
> (Expired certificate), 'not-yet-valid' (Not yet
> valid certificate) and 'other' (all other not
> separately classified certificate errors).

Answer (score 1):

Just install the server certificate in the client's trusted root certificates container (if certified it's expired may not work).
For further details see this post of similar question.

https://stackoverflow.com/a/21238125/3215589

Answer (score 0):

The other answers don't work for me. I'm trying to get the command line working in Jenkins.
All you need are the following command line arguments:

`--non-interactive`

`--trust-server-cert`

Answer (score 0):

from cmd run: SVN List URL
you will be provided with 3 options (r)eject, (a)ccept, (p)ermanently.
enter p.
This resolved issue for me

Answer (score -1):

```
string cmdArguments = $@"/k svn log --trust-server-cert --non-interactive ""{servidor}"" --username alex --password alex -r {numeroRevisao}";
ProcessStartInfo cmd = new ProcessStartInfo("cmd.exe", cmdArguments);

cmd.CreateNoWindow = true;
cmd.RedirectStandardOutput = true;
cmd.RedirectStandardError = true;
cmd.WindowStyle = ProcessWindowStyle.Hidden;
cmd.UseShellExecute = false;

Process reg = Process.Start(cmd);
string output = "";

using (System.IO.StreamReader myOutput = reg.StandardOutput)
{
    output += myOutput.ReadToEnd();
}
using (System.IO.StreamReader myError = reg.StandardError)
{
    output += myError.ReadToEnd();
}

return output;
```

Comment: Can you explain how your code solves his problem? Also, you might want to improve the layout (white-spacing) a bit.

Answer (score -1):

during command line works.  I'm using Ant to commit an artifact after build completes.  Experienced the same issue... Manually excepting the cert did not work (Jenkins is funny that way).  Add these options to your svn command:

--non-interactive

--trust-server-cert