# How to work with SVN 1.7 repositories using Netbeans 7.1?

Tags: svn, netbeans-7, java-7

When trying to update a subversion working copy from Netbeans, I get the following error

```
svn: E175002: Unable to connect to a repository at URL 'https://svn.XXX.de/svn/[RepositoryName]'
svn: E175002: OPTIONS of 'https://svn.XXX.de/svn/[RepositoryName]': Server certificate verification failed: issuer is not trusted (https://svn.XXX.de)
```

Additionally I get a popup window saying

```
SVN command returned with the following error:
javax.net.ssl.SSLProtocolException: handshake alert:  unrecognized_name
```

I know about [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3147660/server-certificate-verification-failed-issuer-is-not-trusted) issue and I successfully made a `svn checkout` using TortoiseSVN. I permanently accepted the server certificate. Accessing and working with working copies from commandline and Tortoise SVN is fine.

Netbeans is started with the `-J-DsvnClientAdapterFactory=commandline` option, so accessing SVN 1.7 repositories basically works.

**NetBeans IDE** 7.1 (Build 201112071828)
**Java** 1.7.0_02; Java HotSpot(TM) Client VM 22.0-b10
**TortoiseSVN** 1.7.6, Build 22632 - 64 Bit
**System** Windows 7 - 64 Bit

What can I do to work with my repositories using Netbeans?

Thanks for any useful hint!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The SVN onfiguration is not automatically import in Netbeans. You can find [here](http://www.jroller.com/peter_pilgrim/entry/developer_note_1_subversion_horror) a brutal way to deal with that (copy svn config in Netbeans).

If you want more accurate informations and elegant way to solve the problem look at [this link](http://charleech.wordpress.com/2010/11/17/java-development-with-netbeans-and-maven-part-4/).

Comment: Thanks, it works! I copied the missing files found in subdirs of `C:\Users\[username]\AppData\Roaming\Subversion\auth` to the appropriate subdirs in `C:\Users\[username]\.netbeans\7.1\config\svn\config\auth\` .

Answer (score 1):

Just install the server certificate in the client's trusted root certificates container:

- Save the certificate to a local file.

If you have access to the server, copy the certificate to your computer.

If not have access to the server but you have chrome, just type the root svn repository URL and click on the paddock (at the left of the https letters), then click in certified data > details tab > copy in file button.

With Internet explorer is similar but the copy in file button will be disabled if the site is not added in the trusted places: internet options > security tab > trusted places > Places > type the subversion URL > add > close and accept all windows > restart explorer. Then, you would be able to save certificate.

- Right click in the certificate > install certificate
- Select all users or current as you need > click next.
- Mark place all certificates in the following store (second option).
- select trusted root certification authorities folder > accept.
- Next > Finish and Ok.
- Restart netbeans.