# Maven scm:add gives error

Tags: java, svn, maven, plugins, commit

I try to commit some files generated by maven in SVN.

```
scm:add -Dmessage="Database SQL's hinzugefuegt" -Dincludes="./src/main/resources/database.sql"
```

I get the following error

```
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-scm-plugin:1.8:add (default-cli) on project GEM: Cannot run add command : Exception while executing SCM command. You must provide at least one file/directory to add -> [Help 1]
```

Where is the problem?

---

EDIT: I changed the directory like `-Dincludes="${base.dir}/src/main/resources/database.sql"`

Now i get this error:

```
Server certificate verification failed: issuer is not trusted (https://svn.msg.de)
```

I found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3147660/server-certificate-verification-failed-issuer-is-not-trusted)  a solution but I have no rights on server. I can only configure the jenkins. Maybe you know how I can embedd **`--trust-server-cert`** in my plugin

Comment: is the includes path correct?

Comment: you might try a pattern in includes `"**/*.sql"` (or try removing it altogether).

Answer (score -2):

From the maven `scm` [page](http://maven.apache.org/scm/plugins/usage.html):

> **The files should be added beforehand by an external scm client.**

Which means that you need to execute either `svn add` command or to open tortoise SVN (or an equivalent) and click `Add` (see screenshot) before executing the `mvn scm:add` command.

[image]

Comment: that description is for the scm "checkin" and "update" goals.