# Jenkins server failing to build because it lacks a certificate that already exists

Tags: msbuild, jenkins, certificate, windows-server-2008-r2

I'm currently migrating a Jenkins server and I'm having trouble getting some projects to build.  The problem projects are failing with this error (which I edited a little for readability):

```
error MSB3326: Cannot import the following key file: . The key file may be 
password protected. To correct this, try to import the certificate again or
import the certificate manually into the current user's personal certificate 
store.

C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\Microsoft.Common.targets(1970,9):
error MSB3321: Importing key file "MyCertificate-LP.pfx" was canceled.   
[D:\Jenkins\jobs\keyword_addin\workspace\KeywordOptimization\
KeywordOptimization.AddIn\KeywordOptimization.AddIn.csproj]
```

The thing is, I've gone and added this certificate to the store of the local system account, which I believe is what Jenkins is running under, and I'm still getting this same error.  Furthermore, what I execute

```
sn -i MyCertificate-LP.pfx personal
```

and enter in the password on a command prompt running under the System account.  I get

```
Failed to install keypair -- Object already exists
```

What's even more confusing is that when I run MSBuild from the command line as the Administrative user I'm signed in as, the build succeeds.

I'm not really sure how to trouble shoot this further.  If I can't figure out the certificate situation with the System account, is there a way to tell Jenkins to run MSBuild as a user other than 'System'?

Comment: //which I believe is what Jenkins is running under,//  You have to make sure.  The identity of what is running the CI process is everything.

Comment: Can you login to the machine with the Identity (local system account)....then try?  Like...at the windows login screen?

Comment: Take a look at this "trick"........... http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17172569/error-while-building-application-using-svn-and-cruisecontrol-net/17196123#17196123