# Problem when trying to use EventLog.SourceExists method in .NET

Tags: c#, .net

I am trying to use eventlogs in my application using C#, so I added the following code

```
if (!EventLog.SourceExists("SomeName"))
EventLog.CreateEventSource("SomeName", "Application");
```

The EventLog.SourceExists causes SecurityException that says
**"The source was not found, but some or all event logs could not be searched.  Inaccessible logs: Security."**

I am running as administrator in Windows 7.

Any help would be appriciated.

Comment: Seems to work fine for me.  Are you running Visual Studio or the program output (.exe) as administrator, i.e., right-click, run as administrator?

Comment: I am not running Visual Studio as administrator. I guess that was the problem. Running the .exe application as administrator also solves the problem.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

This is a permissions problem - you should give the running user permission to read the following registry key:

```
HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\System\CurrentControlSet\Services\EventLog
```

Alternaitvely you can bypas the `CreateEventSource` removing the need to access this registry key.

Both solutions are explained in more detail in the following thread - [How do I create an Event Log source under Vista?](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/forums/en-US/windowsgeneraldevelopmentissues/thread/00a043ae-9ea1-4a55-8b7c-d088a4b08f09/).

Answer (score 11):

Yes, it's a permissions issue, but it's actually worse than indicated by the currently accepted answer. There are actually 2 parts.

## Part 1

In order to use `SourceExists()`, the account that your code is running under must have "Read" permission for the `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\System\CurrentControlSet\Services\EventLog` key **and** it must also have "Read" permissions on each of the descendant-keys. The problem is that *some* of the children of that key don't inherit permissions, and only allow a subset of accounts to read them. E.g. some that I know about:

- Security
- State
- Virtual Server

So you have to also manually change those *when they exist*.

FYI, for those keys (e.g. "State") where even the Administrator account doesn't have "Full Access" permission, you'll have to use [PsExec/PsExec64](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/downloads/psexec) to "fix" things. As indicated in this [StackOverflow answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/78691/530545), download [PsTools](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/downloads/psexec). Run this from an elevated command prompt: `PsExec64 -i -s regedit.exe` and you'll them be able to add the permissions you need to that key.

## Part 2

In order to successfully use `CreateEventSource()`, the account that your code is running under must have "Full Control" permissions on `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\System\CurrentControlSet\Services\EventLog` as well as have "Full Control" permissions on the *log* you're adding the new source to.

## But wait, there's more...

It is also important to know that both `CreateEventSource()` and `WriteEntry()` call `SourceExists()` "under the hood". So ultimately, if you want to use the EventLog class in .Net, you have to change permissions in the registry. The account needs "Full Control" on the `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\System\CurrentControlSet\Services\EventLog` key and "Read" for all children.

**Commentary:** And I believe all of this mess is because when Microsoft originally designed the EventLog, they decided it was critical that people would be able to log something by "Source" without needing to know what log that "Source" went with.

Answer (score 3):

Short tip:

One event source is registered during Service instalation (if application is Windows Service), and can be used without Security Exception with low-profile process owner (not Administrator)

I perform service installation / run with C# code in typical way from SO/ MSDN

Important is property `ServiceName` in class `System.ServiceProcess.ServiceBase` .

Comment: Why or how `ServiceName` is an important property? Is it used as the Event Log Source name as well?

Comment: Creating new "event source" from ordinary application can be blocked by rights system etc. I guess during installation this one event source is magically created (???)

Comment: @JacekCz The `ServiceInstaller`'s class constructor adds an `EventLogInstaller` to its inner `.Installers` collection. This "hidden" `EventLogInstaller` has the same `Source` value as `ServiceInstaller.ServiceName`.

Comment: Three additional notes on this- 1) The auto-creation of the log source can still fail if the installation is not completed with sufficient privileges. 2) The auto-generated code for creating the log source always uses the Application log, so you have to modify the auto-generated code, or add code if you want to use a custom log for your service (we do this to avoid potentially cluttering the Application log). 3) A log source can only be associated with one log, so if you use both the Application log and a custom log, you have to register two separate, and unique, log sources.

Answer (score 0):

Good afternoon,
The simplest is that you run vs2019 as an administrator, so when debugging or excute the service, it will run correctly without generating the exception.

Comment: yuk. I am hoping for a better way.