# Server Error in '/' Application ()

Tags: c#, .net, web-services, visual-studio, odata

I created a OData ADO.NET Framework web api which I am testing in localhost and am getting the error [image]

```
Line 19:             if (!EventLog.SourceExists("MyService"))
```

The StackTrace is:

```
[SecurityException: The source was not found, but some or all event logs could not be searched.  Inaccessible logs: Security.]
   System.Diagnostics.EventLog.FindSourceRegistration(String source, String machineName, Boolean readOnly, Boolean wantToCreate) +657
   System.Diagnostics.EventLog.SourceExists(String source, String machineName, Boolean wantToCreate) +104
   System.Diagnostics.EventLog.SourceExists(String source) +14
```

How should I remove this error ? Thanks a lot.

My web.config has:

```
  <system.web>
    <authentication mode="Windows">
      <forms requireSSL="true" />
    </authentication>
    <authorization>
      <allow roles="MyService" />
      <deny users="*" />
    </authorization>



    <httpCookies requireSSL="true" httpOnlyCookies="true" />
    <compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.5" />
    <httpRuntime targetFramework="4.5" enableVersionHeader="false"/>
  </system.web>
```

Comment: @utility It's a solution with multiple projects.

Comment: try running as admin mode

Comment: Your code has not permission...
read this post : [problem solved](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6735862/problem-when-trying-to-use-eventlog-sourceexists-method-in-net)

Comment: @utility how to run as admin mode ?

Comment: i meant running VS in admin mode

Comment: @utility yes i did. I actually have a solution that was using tfs version control  and how to disable that ? I am getting that could not load assembly involving this tfs filr ? This is the new error. Thanks for ur help.{"Could not load file or assembly 'file:///C:\\

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The process for removing bindings(Team Foundation Service - tfs) is simple:

Ensure you don’t have the solution/projects open in Visual Studio
Copy your solution to a new directory (because the tool does modify files)

Run the utility from the command line: `VSUnbindSourceControl.exe d:\mysolution folder`

Once the tool is finished, all the source control bindings have been removed from any solution and project files.

Also have a look at [this SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/358951/how-can-i-completely-remove-tfs-bindings)