# Jenkins does not execute batch scripts called through ant

Tags: ant, jenkins

Through jenkins the ant file build.xml is invoked with default target. The ant task invokes a batch file which launches a new window and after execution my ant unit tests are executed.

```
<exec dir="${baseLoc}/Temp/${ant.project.name}/@{testdata}" executable="cmd" vmlauncher="false">
            <env key="WAHL" value="@{option}"/>
            <arg line="/c "/>
        <arg value="start /wait __Make.bat"/> 

</exec>
```

The problem is jenkins fails to launch the batch script. Any reason for this ?
Note: The same stuff gets executed through ANT.

Comment: If Jenkins is being run as a Windows Service (not as a user), you might want to check out this [answer to an issue compiling under Jenkins on Windows](http://stackoverflow.com/a/15788921/447438).

Comment: @user2245032 -You may run jenkins under the same user you run the  normal command. If that works, then the problem is with the account jenkins run - system, if that was service.

Comment: Are there any errors in your Jenkins build log?

Answer (score 0):

I recall having similar issues myself running batch files from ant years ago, getting return codes correctly, and so forth. Here's the exec I have used successfully in ant (and ant being run by Jenkins/Hudson) for 5 years:

```
<property name="my.batch.file" value="${path.to.my.file}/myBatch.bat"/>

<exec dir="${dir.property.you.want}" executable="cmd" failonerror="true">
  <!-- any env lines can go here -->
  <arg line="/c call ${my.batch.file}"/> <!-- must be the first arg tag -->
  <arg line="arg1"/> <!-- batch file arguments start here if needed--> 
  <arg line="arg2"/>
</exec>
```

I recommend utilizing ant properties to store the full path to your batch file, and/or make sure the dir entry matches where your batch file is. That could be why it's not running in Jenkins because it's working directory ends up being different.

In your case, you mention it pops up a new window (since you're using start), so you may have to tweak it a little bit to get that behavior.

Answer (score 0):

For some reason i had included the tag **vmlauncher="false"** in exec task. Removing this solved the problem.

Now I'm able to see new command shell for every batch script in execution.

Thanks you for hints and suggestions.