# Using Jenkins to automate TestStack White coded UI tests

Tags: .net, jenkins, continuous-integration, automated-tests, coded-ui-tests

I've created a bunch of coded UI tests for my application using TestStack White.

My next goal is to make those test run automatically at 5 A.M. every morning using Jenkins. Main problem for me now is to launch them within Jenkins Job. First thing that test does is it closes all existing copies of my app, then it creates a new instance of application and finally does some UI stuff.

Tests are working perfectly when I launch them via command line, but when I run identical command within Jenkins job my tests fail. All existing copies of my app close but then tests don't interact with the desktop anyway.

I installed all needed plugins, allowed Jenkins service to interact with desktop and read a lot of topics online and still can't find any resolution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, i figured out what the problem was. I have installed Jenkins as a windows service. In that case Jenkins can't create any external processes. So solution was to stop Jenkins service and run jenkins.war from the command prompt. I leave here link for the answer that helped me.
[Jenkins cannot run exe batch commands?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16245544/jenkins-cannot-run-exe-batch-commands)