# How to delete the localdb instance owned by System

Tags: sql-server, localdb

I deleted the localdb instance files which were located in

> "C:\Windows\System32\config\systemprofile\AppData\Local\Microsoft\Microsoft
>   SQL Server Local DB\Instances\v11.0"

by accident. The system cannot start the localdb instance now. The way that I know how to fix the issue is to delete the instance by command

> "sqllocaldb delete instancename"

, and re-create the instance again. But I found this approach could only work for user account if I deleted the instances files located in

> "C:\Users\UserName\AppData\Local\Microsoft\Microsoft SQL Server Local
>   DB\Instances\v11.0"

So how can I solve this problem to delete the db instance owned by System?

Comment: i think this should be migrated to .. http://dba.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Get PsExec from here:
http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb897553.aspx

Run cmd.exe as LocalSystem as demonstrated in this link:
[How do you run CMD.exe under the Local System Account?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77528/how-do-you-run-cmd-exe-under-the-local-system-account) `psexec -i -s cmd.exe`

Now you can run
    `SqlLocalDb stop InstanceName`
and
    `SqlLocalDb delete InstanceName`

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried deleting the folder as well? I **think** the instance should be discovered as deleted if this folder is gone, and it should be recreated. (not 100% sure though; definitely back it up before deleting).

```
"C:\Windows\System32\config\systemprofile\AppData\Local\Microsoft\Microsoft SQL Server Local DB\Instances\v11.0"
```

Answer (score 0):

You can fix the issue by copying the files you deleted from other machine. Please make sure that you copy from other machine's "C:\Windows\System32\config\systemprofile\AppData\Local\Microsoft\Microsoft SQL Server Local DB\Instances\v11.0".

I'm not sure how to delete the db instance owned by System for now.