# Sonar Runner SVN error E230001

Tags: svn, sonarqube, sonar-runner

Trying to analyze a project with sonar-runner brings the following error up:

```
ERROR: Error during Sonar runner execution
ERROR: Unable to execute Sonar
ERROR: Caused by: The svn blame command [svn blame --xml --non-interactive -x -w src/main/java/[...].java] failed: svn: E230001: Unable to connect to a repository at URL 'https://[...]/trunk/src/main/java/[...].java'
svn: E230001: Server SSL certificate verification failed: issuer is not trusted
```

If I run a `svn list https://[...]` it works after permanently trusting the cert, but it still won't work in sonar-runner.

I think adding `--trust-server-cert` to the `svn blame` command would fix it, but I don't know of a way to do this (is this configurable via properties? I couldn't find a comprehensive list of possible properties anywhere).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, as it turns out, permanently accepting the certificate running a `svn list` (or any other command) against the server works. What didn't work was that I was doing this from a different user than the one running sonar-runner.

If it helps anyone: I am running sonar-runner from Atlassian Bamboo, which runs as a Windows service (system user). In order to do the workaround, you'll need a command-line as the system user. To achieve this, view [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77528/how-do-you-run-cmd-exe-under-the-local-system-account).

Answer (score -1):

This helped me resolve my issue which was code collaborator connecting to svn secure. I had run svn list as the serviceaccount I had configured in the collaborator UI, but the collaborator windows service account was running as local host.  So instead of running the svn list as local host, I changed the windows service to run under the same user account that I had accepted the svn certificate under.