# How to connect as NT AUTHORITY\SYSTEM to svn?

Tags: windows, authentication, svn, visualsvn-server

I have a service running at local system account (NT AUTHORITY\SYSTEM). This service shall connect to local subversion repository. Is this possible?

I tried this

```
svn export --non-interactive http://localhost/svn/MyRepository TargetFolder
```

but it does not work. As far as I know I cannot set any password for "NT AUTHORITY\SYSTEM". I don't like to use my personal account and put my password there as clear text.

My SVN runs on VisualSVN-Server

Comment: I'm not familiar with VisualSVN-Server, but in general, single sign-on authentication systems see connections from the local system account as connections from the computer's domain account, i.e., COMPUTERNAME$.  It may be as simple as granting this account the appropriate access rights.

Comment: Of course, I granted access to svn repository for this user. But it does not work. I think I will simply create a local user on this machine and use that one.

Comment: @HarryJohnston No, LOCAL account represents Anonymous account credentials on network. It's Network Service that represents COMPUTERNAME$ on the network.

Comment: See http://serverfault.com/questions/135867/how-to-grant-network-access-to-localsystem-account

Comment: @bahrep: the question and the accepted answer both say the same thing I did.  The SYSTEM (aka LocalSystem) account has the same network access as NetworkService.  Try it yourself!

Comment: @HarryJohnston TY, going to double-check this again. You should never use LocalSystem account for such tasks anyway.

Answer (score 0):

You should never use SYSTEM account for such tasks for numerous security reasons. Create and use a dedicated local Windows or Active Directory account with limited permissions.

Answer (score -1):

Setting up the cached authentication credentials for the System user requires running an svn.exe command as the System user.  Windows Vista+/Server 2008+ doesn't make that easy.

1. ​Install psexec from https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/downloads/psexec
2. Start an elevated cmd.exe as Administrator.
3. Run "psexec -i -s cmd.exe".
4. A new cmd.exe should appear which is running as the System user.
5. Type whoami.  Verify the output reads something like "nt authority\system".
6. Perform a subversion command like "svn --username your-svn-user list your-https-repo-url".​
7. When prompted by svn.exe, enter the password for your-svn-user.
8. ​The "svn auth" command allows you to examine the cached credentials.

Note if a new SSL certificate is installed on the Subversion server, you'll have to repeat this process.

For more responses on this topic: [How do you run CMD.exe under the Local System Account?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77528/how-do-you-run-cmd-exe-under-the-local-system-account/78691#78691)