# Access denied to cmake and Visual studio

Tags: git, visual-studio-2012, cmake

I am facing a very frustrating access denied error without any other information.

I have `git clone` 'd a repository to a folder, naimly to `~\Desktop\bempp`. When i try to `cmake` by typing in the cmd `cmake -DCMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX=<install_dir> ..` I get an error message Access denied. install_dir is `~\Desktop\bempp` . Instructions are here under the title compiling bem++:http://www.bempp.org/installation.html

I also tried to cmake with the gui (it succeeded), then build with visual studio (succeeded again), but once more when I try to run it I get: 
Unable to start program ~\bem\x64\Release\ALL_BUILD access denied.

I tried to remove the read-only nature of the folder and the subfolders, but they come back automatically. After more googling it turns out that attrib has to be used:

my call is:

```
attrib -r +s C:\Users\nempa001\Desktop\bempp /s /d
```

The call simply does ***not*** work. Apart from not working recursively as said in each description page (check this) https://www.lifewire.com/attrib-command-2625802 , even if I `attrib +s` each one of the folders in the path shown in the Visual studio message (these attrib call succeed, I check it through attrib ), I still get the same error from Visual Studio.

I am the owner of the folder in **properties** and also I have **full control** rights and there is system endpoint center protection on my computer(maybe irrelevant). This whole situation makes zero sense.

Am I towards the right direction? I am totally out of ideas, can anyone propose a solution?

Comment: Out of security reasons there are some folders in Windows a program can only change when the program is running with administrator privileges. Did you try to right click on `cmd.exe` and use `Run as admimistrator`? I had a similar problem and used [`PrivBar`](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/aaron_margosis/2004/07/24/privbar-an-ieexplorer-toolbar-to-show-current-privilege-level/) to check my/the programs privilege level. Otherwise see ["How do you run CMD.exe under the Local System Account?"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77528)

Comment: yes, I have found that. However, I can run it as administrator and nothing changes

Comment: Could you please add your error message(s) and more information on the environment your running in? I tried to reproduce your problem and with CMake Visual Studio generator I get the following errors: `Could NOT find PkgConfig (missing: PKG_CONFIG_EXECUTABLE)` and `Environment scripts not implemented on non-UNIX systems`. So something is missing in your problems description to enable us to reproduce your problem.

Comment: Florian thanks for your help. It turns out if your system is non unix, the cmake is interrupted. Nothing to be done, the error is pretty self explanatory  and a dead-end for a windows machine as it seems.